# Non-Equi Self Join

Tags: sql, oracle, self-join

I have the following user table

### USERS

```
name    city
A       New York
B       Paris
C       London
D       London
E       Paris
```

I want to select the two users from the same City using non equi self join
such that the result follows

```
name  name  city
B     E     Paris
C     D     London
```

Comment: Tag your DBMS please.

Comment: Please explain your requirement (not to use equi self join).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "self-join" is just like a normal join execpet that the same table appears on both sides of the join clause. "non-equi" means finding rows which don't match on some column.

So in your case you need to join on CITY and filter on differences in NAME:

```
select t1.name as t1_name
       , t2.name as t2_name
       , t1.city
from users t1
     join users t2
     on t2.city = t1.city
where t1.name < t2.name
```

Note the filter condition is `less than`: using `not equals` would double the result set.(*)

Obviously this solution will work where CITY has two entries. If there are more than two entries you will still get multiple rows (one per combination).

---

(*) Some times using `!=` is desirable: if we're investigating a data quality issue then returning all columns from both rows can help us understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below way with the use of cte also

```
WITH CITY
AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A.CITY ORDER BY A.CITY) RNO,A.NAME,A.CITY FROM Table1 A
)

SELECT A.NAME,B.NAME,A.CITY FROM 
CITY A JOIN 
CITY B
ON 
A.city=B.city AND A.NAME<>B.name AND A.RNO<=B.RNO
```

Comment: Not sure what this solution brings to the party, but if you're going to do this it would make more sense to order the partition clause by NAME rather than CITY.

Comment: @APC User need to select two users for same city so i used partition with city so for this scenario it got results as expected.

Comment: My point is, the CTE adds overhead to the execution cost without materially affecting the result set. So what advantage do you think this query offers to justify the extra cost?

Comment: @APC I thought like hitting two time a physical table may not be a good practice so i have taken results in cte and used it down. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I think this falls under the category of "premature optimization". Also, have you run an Explain Plan over your solution? Try it, you might be surprised! ;)